# Drop foreign schema in PostgreSQL using a foreign data wrapper

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Using the MySQL foreign data wrapper in PostgreSQL there is a nice trick that enables you to quickly tell Postgres about all the tables in a MySQL database.  It is as follows:

`IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA my_favourite_database FROM SERVER mysql_server INTO public;`

There is no analog `DROP FOREIGN SCHEMA`. Although `DROP FOREIGN TABLE` could be done piecemeal for each table, this also requires knowing the names of all tables in the foreign database.  I am also uncertain if this command actually `DROP`s the table in the foreign database or just the connection to it.

How would one approach this automatically.

I imagine the same approach would apply to any foreign data wrapper in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`drop foreign table` only drops the "local" foreign table definitions, not the table in the remote sever.

You can drop all foreign tables with a short PL/pgSQL block:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
begin
  for l_rec in (select foreign_table_schema, foreign_table_name 
                from information_schema.foreign_tables) loop
     execute format('drop foreign table %I.%I', l_rec.foreign_table_schema, l_rec.foreign_table_name);
  end loop;
end;
$$
```

This will drop **all** foreign tables in the current database. If you want to limit that to certain tables only, you can adjust the query in the `for` loop accordingly, e.g. by selecting only those for a specific foreign server `where foreign_server_name = 'mysql'`

I would also put all those foreign tables into a separate schema to separate them from the the "regular" tables - but that is a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of iterating through all tables you can drop the whole schema and import again:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS ramu cascade;
CREATE SCHEMA ramu;
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA ramu FROM SERVER ramsingh INTO ramu;
```